# GRASS GIS: how to run g.run_command("v.extract") in Python with sqlite, smooth-spline in GRASS GIS?

Tags: python-2.7, grass.script, grass-7.0

I would like to solve several problems by using a python script in 
GRASS GIS:

I already uploaded collected GPS-waypoints and tracks ("v.in.org"), patched several GPS-vector data ("v.patch") and updated the attribute tables ("db.in.org","v.db.join"). I want generate a trail network, every trail is seperated in different sections (point vector data). In between the sections I tracked myself every minute (point data).

Now, I want to extract the waypoints of one trail (new vector) and connect the sections. Therefore, I tried:

```
>>>sqlite="""substr(cmt,1,4)='R001'"""
>>>print sqlite
>>>substr(cmt,1,4)='R001'
>>>g.run_command("v.extract", overwrite=True, input="rec_RG", output="test", where=sqlite)  

0
```

As a second step I would like to connect the point data. I used the command "v.to.lines", but somehow GRASS integrates the area in between all points. How do I only connect the point-vector data from th beginning to the end? What do I need to add? I could not find any specific information in the manuel.

I tried:

```
g.run_command("v.to.lines", overwrite=True, input="spl_"+Nr_RG[i], output="spl_line"+Nr_RG[i])
```